# What happens to memory when I dereference a pointer and assign the value to some variable?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, dereference

I have a class that has a private string pointer.  This class also has a public method that dereferences that string pointer and returns the resultant string to the caller.  My question is this: what happens to the memory that holds the dereferenced string?

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class myclass
{
    private:
        std::string *_name;

    public:
        myclass()
        {
            this->_name = new std::string("my name");
        }

        ~myclass()
        {
            delete this->_name;
        }

        std::string getName()
        {
            return *this->_name;
        }
};

void main()
{
    myclass m;
    {
        std::string str = m.getName(); //what happens to this memory?
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
    } //str deleted here (I think)
    //here, the m._name pointer hasn't yet been deleted
}
```

In my main function, the variable `str` gets assigned the dereferenced string.  What happens to the memory that holds this string?  I think that the memory is held on the stack and therefore gets "de-allocated" automatically when the variable goes out of scope.  What confuses me is that the private string pointer may still be in scope even if the dereferenced string is no longer in scope.  Does the `str` variable get assigned a copy of the private `_name` pointer's value?

If this code does copy the string in the background, should I be concerned about performance.  Would my code run faster if I simply have `getName()` return the `_name` pointer without dereferencing it?

Comment: It is being copied obviously.. if you return the address of the private variable you are exposing it to be changed by any outside program. I don't think that is what you are looking for here..

Comment: `std::string getName()` is returning a copy of a string. `str` value copies the value from a copy of the string pointed to by `_name`.  A better approach would be to define getName() as `const std::string& getName() const { return *(this->_name); }`

Comment: Dereference and deallocation are two different things: with the former we access the memory position pointed by the pointer, with the latter we free the memory of that specific variable.

Comment: Off-topic, but you probably do not want a pointer-to-string as a member. Just use string as it is.

Comment: @jodag, does `getName()` deallocate anything?  Is it doing anything more than dereferencing the pointer?  And, can you explain why your `getName()` definition is better?  Is it that the `const` keywords are saying something about what the function does with its private members?

Comment: @user2023861 getName() is not deallocating anything, your dereferencing the string in the function then returning a copy of the string. This copy is then copied again into str. Returning the string with the & causes it to return a reference to `*_name` without making a copy, then it will be copied into `str`. The reason it is `const` is so that you don't break encapsulation. If it wasn't const you would be getting direct access to the private member variable pointed to by `_name` which may be what you want, but it would be different than your current `getName()` implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you don't need a pointer. Second, you can return a copy (like you do) or a reference (or pointer if you want to stick with that), but there are pros and cons to either approach:

```
class myclass
{
private:
    std::string _name;
public:
    myclass() : _name("my name")
    {
    }
    std::string getName1() { return _name; }
    std::string& getName2() { return _name; }
    const std::string& getName3() const { return _name; }
}
```

`getName1` returns by value. The con is that a copy gets made, which can impact performance, but the returned value is safe to use after the object goes out of scope.

The difference between `getName2` and `getName3` is that you can use the former to modify the actual member of the class. The con is that the reference can no longer be used if the object goes out of scope, so you'd be left with a dangling reference. The pro is that it's more efficient, since there's no copying involved.

```
myclass x;
std::string a = x.getName1(); // copy is made
std::string& b = x.getName2(); // no copy
                               // b is mutable
b = "something else";  //this will modify x._name
const std::string& c = x.getName3; // no copy
                                   // c is const

myclass* y = new myclass;
std::string d = x.getName1();  // copy is made
std::string& e = x.getName2(); // no copy
delete y;
d = "something else"; //legal
e = "something else"; //undefined behavior, e is a dangling reference
```

Comment: If I do this `std::string str2 = m->getName2();`, (no ampersand), will str2 be a copy?  In my testing, it looks like str2 sticks around even after `delete y`.

Comment: @user2023861 yes, it's a copy.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the "rule of three". If you define any of: copy constructor, assignment operator, destructor, then define all of them. Then there will be no confusion whether the pointer to the string was deleted: you would just have a new one created in the corresponding assignment operator.